# Flask and error handling BadRequest exception

Tags: python, flask

I have simple view like that:

```
@blueprint.route('/')
def index():
    '''CMS splash page!'''
    print request.form['no-key-like-that']

    return render_template('home/splash.html', title='Welcome')
```

The goal of that view is to cause BadRequest error on Flask. That happens and I got very generic error page in the process that says:

```
Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

However I want to intercept all errors and serve them wrapped in our templates for better look and feel, I do this like that:

```
@app.errorhandler(TimeoutException)
def handle_timeout(error):
    if utils.misc.request_is_xhr(request):
        return jsonify({'api_timeout': True}), 503

    return redirect(url_for('errors.api_timeout', path=request.path))
```

However the same cannot be done for BadRequest exception, I tried:

```
@app.errorhandler(werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestError)
def handle_bad_request(error):
    return render_template(
        'errors/bad_request.html',
        exception_message=unicode(error),
        return_path=request.path), 400
```

And:

```
@app.errorhandler(werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError)
def handle_bad_request(error):
    return render_template(
        'errors/bad_request.html',
        exception_message=unicode(error),
        return_path=request.path), 400
```

And:

```
@app.errorhandler(werkzeug.exceptions.HttpError)
def handle_bad_request(error):
    return render_template(
        'errors/bad_request.html',
        exception_message=unicode(error),
        return_path=request.path), 400
```

In each case, instead of my bad_request.html there is raw response I mentioned above.

```
Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

What actually works for me:

```
# NOTE: for some reason we cannot intercpet BadRequestKeyError, didn't
# figure out why. Thus I have added check if given 400 is
# BadRequestKeyError if so display standard api error page. This happens
# often when dev tries to access request.form that does not exist.
@app.errorhandler(400)
def handle_bad_request(error):
    if isinstance(error, werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError):
        if utils.misc.request_is_xhr(request):
            return jsonify({
                'api_internal_error': True,
                'error': unicode(error)
            }), 500

        return render_template(
            'errors/api_internal.html',
            exception_message=unicode(error),
            return_path=request.path), 500
```

However as you can see it's far from perfection as error 400 is not necessarily always BadRequestKeyError.

Because exception handling works for any other exception but not BadRequest family it keeps me wondering, is it a bug? Or perhaps I am doing something wrong.

Comment: the `@app.errorhandler()` will be called for every `HTTP 400` response. You'll have to put logic into your application to deal with different cases.